# How to auto-filter multiple conditions by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter 4 "or" and 2 "and" conditions.

```
The string contains both "Bank of America" and "Chargeback"
or contains both "BOFA" and "CHGBK"
or contains both "American Express" and "CHGBCK"
or contains both "BOFA" and "Chargeback"
```

Which means there are 4 conditions in total, and each condition must contains 2 string.

I have attached my coding blow, but it doesn't work. Please advise! Thanks a lot!

```
Worksheets("xBofA_Modified").Activate
arr1 = Array("*Bank of America*", "*Chargeback*")
arr2 = Array("*BOFA*", "*CHGBK*")
arr3 = Array("*American Express*", "*CHGBCK*")
arr4 = Array("*BOFA*", "*Chargeback*")

Worksheets("xBofA_Modified").Rows("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=11, _
    Criteria1:=arr1, _
    Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria2:=arr2, _
    Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria3:=arr3, _
    Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria4:=arr4, _
    opertator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Try changing the Rows("1:1") to something like UsedRange.  Also the leftmost field is field one; so make sure Field:=11 is what you want.  Please show some values that are in field 11.

Comment: I assume using a helpler column is not an option? That would probably be easiest, then a basic filter based on a True/False excel formula. No VBA needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly (as I know) there is no way to complete this task with AutoFilter.
Howerer you could use a workaround. Try something like this:

```
Sub main()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xBofA_Modified")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
    If (InStr(cell.Value, "Bank of America") > 0 And InStr(cell.Value, "Chargeback") > 0) = False And _
       (InStr(cell.Value, "BOFA") > 0 And InStr(cell.Value, "CHGBK") > 0) = False And _
       (InStr(cell.Value, "American Express") > 0 And InStr(cell.Value, "CHGBCK") > 0) = False And _
       (InStr(cell.Value, "BOFA") > 0 And InStr(cell.Value, "Chargeback") > 0) = False _
    Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

This code is looping thru each cell in column K (11th column) and then is Hiding the rows which doesn't apply to any of your criteria.
It is not very elegant solution to complete this, but the result is pretty much the same as you would get with AutoFilter.